# How can i transfer a file from Angular to a C# Web API

Tags: c#, angular, file

I need to post a File from angular with code like this:

```
addBudgetAttachment(budgetCode:string, file: File){
    const url = environment.webServiceUrl + "Attachments?budgetId=" + budgetCode;
    return this.http.post<string>(url,file);
  }
```

To a C# WEB API that does something like this:

```
public string Post([FromBody] FileStream file, string budgetId){
    return budgetId;
}
```

And in this C# method save the file in a directory, I've been trying with everything possible and nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented post method in c# so you have to send data from angular in http post method body like this.

```
addBudgetAttachment(budgetCode:string, file: File){
    const url = environment.webServiceUrl;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('budgetCode', budgetCode);
    return this.http.post<string>(url,formData);
  }
```